# Trim/Crop Audio file: ObjectiveC/ObjectiveC++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, audio, objective-c++

I am trying to crop the audio. So far i haven't found any lead where i can do some coding with it. This is the only documentation lead i got
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/index.html

Is there a sample where Extended Audio File Service has been used in any example app. This would be really helpful.

Is there even any Open Source app or small code snippet which could really help me with base where i could start something. My main objective is to crop audio at certain duration point A to Point B and merge new audio in between in place of cropped space.

Edit:
If there is C/C++ solution then it would also help, provided i could implement that in ObjectiveC++. I am open to [openFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc/) based solution too.

Comment: There is unlikely to be an Objective-C based solution for this; it's far more likely to be written in C or C++, so widen your search (edit your tags).